# Google Analytics tracking code on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am working on a WordPress site where some google analytics code is already in place and working for some pages like:

```
http://www.samplesite.com/aboutus/
```

however on other pages, it doesn't work:

```
http://www.samplesite.com/portfolio/
```

The person who put the tracking code said he put it on the header.php where some pages worked while others didn't.

My task was to make it work on those pages so I placed it at the bottom part (before the closing body tag) of Footer.php

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-<tracking id>, 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However after 24 hours on Google Analytics page -> Admin -> Property -> Tracking Info the status of the pages is:

```
Tracking Not Installed
```

Why is it not working? What should I do? Thank you in advance

Comment: View your page source and make sure it is actually rendering on the page...

Comment: it does show the tracking code but still the status is: Tracking Not Installed

Comment: @vishnu header.php is common for all pages in common templates of wordpress. footer also common. Please make sure is there is any patch called in the template for additional header and footer in your template. If the template have patch plz add this same stuff in both files.

Comment: @Nith what do you mean patch?

Comment: if you are using wordpress then why not you use the following plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-analytics/

Comment: @vishnu additional code that used to split the common header

Comment: @Nith can you please give a sample code of the patch on wordpress sites?

Comment: @Nith there is other files ending with "header.php" like about-header.php. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @vishnu may be a chance some developers using different header files inside wp templates for separate styles and functions. Something like this. But not so sure what is inside that.

Answer (score 2):

If playing with code isn't your thing, there are plugins that can place the Adsense code for you. You could try Google Analtyics WP plugin.